# Laravel Eloquent - Eager Loading Query is Being Restricted by limit()

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I have the following query:

```
MyTable::where('my_column', '=', 25)->with('myOtherTable')
                                    ->orderBy('id', DESC)->limit(5);
```

I would like the above to bring me results analogoous to the following raw SQL query:

```
SELECT *
FROM myTable AS ABB1 
    LEFT JOIN myOtherTable AS ABB2 ON ABB1.id = ABB2.myTable_id
WHERE my_column = 25
ORDER BY myTable.id DESC
LIMIT 5;
```

The above will find everything in `myTable` along with corresponding info from `myOtherTable` and ***then*** limit the results to 5 rows.

When I run the eloquent statement above, two SQL queries are processed.  The first looks something like:

```
SELECT * 
FROM myTable
WHERE my_column = 25
ORDER BY id DESC;
```

If this query returns say 7 result items, but I pass in a smaller number into the `limit()` function (ie. `limit(5)`), then the corresponding eager loading query will look like:

```
SELECT *
FROM myOtherTable
WHERE id IN(1, 2, 3, 4, 5);
```

The eager loading query is itself limited to 5 items.  There should be no limit here.  The number of items in the `IN` conditional above should be 7 (or whatever the count returned from the first query is).  The limit should only be applied after the second query runs.

How would I do this with Eloquent?

Answer (score 0):

You can use eloquent's `join`.

```
MyTable::join('myOtherTable', 'column_id', '=', 'id')
    ->where('my_column', '=', 25)
    ->with('myOtherTable')
    ->orderBy('id', DESC)
    ->limit(5);
```

The `with` is only if you want to eager load the relation on `MyTable`.